# How can I use SOCKS with HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit, socks

Is it possible to use HtmlUnit through SOCKS proxy? Could anyone please provide a code sample?

====

So I've dug through webclient sources, here's the best way I can think of:

1. Subclass `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` so that it allows setting SOCKS info and if it is set, before returning a Connection, sets SOCKS parameters
2. Subclass `WebConnection` - rewrite `createHttpClient` so that it uses a manager from step 1 and add a method to get that manager directly or http client at first (it is *protected* now - so bad...)
3. To use 1) create a `WebClient` instance 2) Create subclassed `WebConnection` 3) Set it to be used by `WebClient` 4) Access connection's manager and use it's methods to use socks

Comment: how did you ultimately solved this problem of having different socks proxy for different instances of webclient?

Comment: @XCoder, I didn't have to since htmlunit 2.8 came out and it's configurable since that version

Comment: yup! I too found it, thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlUnit uses HttpClient as the underlying connection library, I investigated this a little, but:

```
1- Couldn't find a way to configure HttpClient (except by the generic Java Socks mechanism defined in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)
2- Do not have access to a public Socks Proxy to test against
```

Comment: Works in 2.8 due to the newer httpclient. You're one of the developers, right? Thanks for your work.

Comment: Yes, I am one of the team. 2.8 is supporting SOCKS, even at request level, enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set the [appropriate system properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) before creating your `WebClient` object.  For example:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "localhost"); // replace "localhost" with your proxy server
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "9999"); // replace "9999" with your proxy port number

WebClient client = new WebClient();
```

At this point, HttpClient (which is used by HtmlUnit under the covers) will pick up the settings and use the SOCKS proxy for all network communication.

**UPDATE:** I read your revised question (and your comment) and I think you're on the right track.  The problem is that if you implement step 1 using the above system properties, then your code is not thread-safe (because those system properties are global).  One solution is to synchronize on something, but of course this can introduce performance problems (may not matter to you).

If you *really* want to control this in a per-socket basis, then I think you will need to do something like the following:

1. Create a custom `ProtocolSocketFactory` that passes a `java.net.Proxy` object to the `Socket` constructor (like in [this example](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/40118)).
2. Create a custom `Protocol` that uses this `ProtocolSocketFactory`.
3. Apply this `Protocol` to the new connections in your custom connection manager using `HttpConnection.setProtocol()`.

I haven't actually tested this, but based on a quick glance at the HttpClient 3.1 source code, I think that's how it would be done.  I would love to hear how you ultimately solve this problem :-).  Good luck!

Comment: This way I'll be setting SOCKS properties to all WebClient instances. I want to be able to set different proxy servers for different instances